# Store and return a string with HTML and Tagged template literals in JS

Tags: javascript, string, template-literals

Here is how template looks like

```
var itemTemplate = function(data) {

        return `<div class="title">${data.name}</div>
        <div class="content">${data.user_id}</div>
        `;

    };
```

I am trying to store it in DB as JSON and return to replace above code as

```
 node_temp = object.template;
 var itemTemplate = function(data) {
    
            return node_temp;
    
        };
```

which ofcourse is not working because backticks are not there.

Tried ways like below but I get "data not defined" error as code below evaluates rather just returning string with backticks.

```
const fillTemplate = function(nodeTemp) {
            return new Function("return `" + nodeTemp + "`;");
        }

return fillTemplate(node_temp);
```

Can someone suggest what how I can return a dynamic string containing html and template literal with backticks without evaluating or suggest a better way to do it?
Much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Generally, using `new Function` or `eval` are terrible ideas.

Comment: Either store the whole function body in your database (and make sure only privileged users are able to edit the *code*), or don't use template literals at all but a proper templating engine.

Comment: @Aplet123 how else I can print template literal then?  Bergi Is it for this particular case or in general?

Comment: @aplet123 I am using it with a script that already accepts template literals. Is there something that can be used that results in template literals bcoz thats what will be required in the end.